# How to Export DataTables to XML as nested

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, nested, dataset

Using C#, I have defined a DataSet. And inside DataSet I have defined several DataTables which are exported to XML.

Current C# code:

```
DataSet dataset = new DataSet("newDataSet");

DataTable Table2 = new DataTable("Table2");
Table2.Columns.Add("Point1");
Table2.Columns.Add("Point2");
Table2.Columns.Add("Point3");
Table2.Columns.Add("Point4");
Table2.Columns.Add("Point5");

Table2.Rows.Add(
    ("00:00:00" + ", " + 800),
    ("02:45:00" + ", " + 330),
    ("05:35:00" + ", " + 350),
    ("12:35:00" + ", " + 405),
    ("1.00:00:00" + ", " + 175),
)

DataTable Table1 = new DataTable("Table1");
Table1.Columns.Add("id");
Table1.Columns.Add("Button");
Table1.Columns.Add("ButtonAttribution");
Table1.Columns.Add("ExtendedCommand");
Table1.Columns.Add("Name");

Table1.Rows.Add("101", Buttons[i].ButtonID, Buttons[i].ButtonAtribution, Buttons[i].ExtendedCommand, Buttons[i].DayRoutine1.NameCombo);

Table1.Merge(Table2);
dataset.WriteXml(path);
```

Current XML result:

```
<Table1>
    <id>101</id>
    <Button>0</Button>
    <ButtonAttribution>NoTagAtributted</ButtonAttribution>
    <ExtendedCommand>DayRoutine1</ExtendedCommand>
    <Name>Day Routine 1</Name>
</Table1>
<Table1>
    <Point1>00:00:00, 570</Point1>
    <Point2>01:35:00, 205</Point2>
    <Point3>08:20:00, 450</Point3>
    <Point4>13:40:00, 245</Point4>
    <Point5>21:20:00, 1010</Point5>
</Table1>
```

Desired output in XML:

```
<Table1>
    <id>101</id>
    <Button>0</Button>
    <ButtonAttribution>NoTagAtributted</ButtonAttribution>
    <ExtendedCommand>DayRoutine1</ExtendedCommand>
    <Name>Day Routine 1</Name>
    <Table2>
        <Point1>00:00:00, 800</Point1>
        <Point2>02:45:00, 330</Point2>
        <Point3>05:35:00, 350</Point3>
        <Point4>12:35:00, 405</Point4>
        <Point5>1.00:00:00, 175</Point5>
    </Table2>
</Table1>
```

How I can achieve this structure with DataTables and DataSets?

Comment: [Nested table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sfkwf9s(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: You should add Relation between those tables. There is no field in Table2 to act as relation column. IMHO it would be much simpler to do this directly with XElement, if you don't want to use a database to retrieve the dataset and XML from.

Comment: Why do you want a table inside a table?  Normally table 2 should contain the same ID as table 1 and use the ID to Join the two tables when necessary.